# How to create a metric that shows the average record count per day of year?

Tags: kibana-7

I'm currently working on data visualization in Kibana and I'm trying to create a metric that displays the average record count per day of the year. I have a timestamp field in my data, and I want to calculate the average number of records for each day of the year.

I examined TSVB, aggregation based visualizations, I couldn't find anything